What am I missing in my attempts to automate the iptables and redsocks setup inside a docker container?
I am using a script to setup custom iptables and restart redsocks. It works when I manually run inside a running container, but I want the container to automatically set it up. I thought I could do this with CMD in my dockerfile, but it's not working. What am I missing?
Here is the Dockerfile:
# Dockerfile
# https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/discussions/1600
ARG CHROME_VERSION

FROM selenoid/chrome:${CHROME_VERSION:-latest} as selenoid_chrome

FROM python:3.10-bookworm as patcher

RUN pip install undetected-chromedriver

COPY --from=selenoid_chrome /usr/bin/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver

COPY patch_driver.py .

RUN python3 patch_driver.py

FROM selenoid_chrome

USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -qy
RUN apt-get install iptables redsocks curl wget lynx -qy

COPY --from=patcher /usr/bin/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver

COPY redsocks.conf /etc/redsocks.conf
COPY iptables-config.sh /etc/iptables-config.sh

RUN chmod +x /etc/iptables-config.sh

CMD [ "bash", "/etc/iptables-config.sh" ]

ENV DRIVER_ARGS="--headless=new --start-maximized --window-size=1024,1620 --disable-dev-shm-usage --remote-debugging-pipe --no-sandbox --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' --verbose"

RUN AAA=$(echo '#!/bin/bash\necho $DRIVER_ARGS' ; cat /entrypoint.sh ; ) && echo "$AAA" > /entrypoint.sh

USER selenium


And here is the shell script I am trying to run:
#!/bin/bash
#https://medium.com/@jogarcia/breaking-the-proxy-walls-with-redsocks-in-linux-f4c1bfb6fb6a

# Configura iptables para que todo el trafico local vaya directamente y el resto
# siempre que tenga autorizacion (grupo socksified) vaya a internet a traves de redsocks

# Create new chain
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS

# Ignore LANs and some other reserved addresses.
# See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses
# and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735 for full list of reserved networks.
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 198.18.0.0/15 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

# Anything else should be redirected to port 12345
#iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345 and 12346

iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12346
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

# Any tcp connection made should be redirected to the REDSOCKS CHAIN.
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDSOCKS

# Restart Redsocks
/etc/init.d/redsocks restart

EDIT:
This is the docker compose file I am using this with:
version: "3.9"

services:
  selenium:
    image: uc_chrome:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.uc
    restart: "no"
    container_name: airflow_uc
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - ./proxy_manager:/lpm
    ports:
      - "5900-5999:4444"


Two things: Docker normally fully controls the container's environment, and I'd expect all of these iptables commands to fail; and it looks like your script will otherwise run to the end and exit, and when it does, the container exits too.  You need some process running in the foreground, not an init script.

I don't see a problem description here. What's not working? Are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior? Something else?

@DavidMaze Well, I'm able to start the container (actually using docker-compsoe) and if I docker exec and run the script, it works manually.

@larsks Well, my expectation is that the shell scripts runs the commands, and restarts redsoscks in the container. However, it is not doing so. But if I were to docker exec and run the shell script inside the running container, it works. I want this done automatically instead of me having to do it manually.

A container only runs one process normally.  If it's running your script, then it's not running a SOCKS proxy to be restarted.  Do you need to exec the proxy, as a foreground process, as the last thing in your script?

@DavidMaze No, the proxy is not part of this container. This container just contains chrome and has slenium and undetected chrome_driver installed. I actually have a custom hook that essentially allows me to start the driver remotely. However, what the iptables and redsocks does is route all traffic to to another container with the proxy because setting the proxy in the driver options wasn't working for me. When I use docker exec, it is to run the iptables commands and restart redsocks.
